# Save a Select Query in a variable and use it in update and insert

Tags: mysql, database

I have a procedure where I want to bring some data of one table (A) to an other (B), updating Bs rows if some of the columns are equal and inserting a new row, if this is not the case.
Afterwards I want to delete all of those rows from table A (leaving the ones which were not queried from the select statement and those which were added through another process between the update/insert and delete statement of the procedure).

For that use case I want to store the result of a select query in a variable and then working insert and update on it before I delete every entry from the result.

Thanks for your help.
Martin

UPDATE:
I did the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`martin`@`%` PROCEDURE `validateData`()
BEGIN
select * from write_data as temp_write_data;

UPDATE read_data AS r
    LEFT JOIN 
    temp_write_data as w
    ON [...]
    SET [...]
    WHERE [...];

INSERT INTO read_data AS r
    SELECT [...]
    FROM temp_write_data
    WHERE [...];

DELETE write_data.* FROM write_data
    LEFT JOIN temp_write_data
    using(guid)
    WHERE temp_write_data.somecolumn is not null;
end//
```

But that does not work, I fear.

SOLUTION:

I used:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_write_data AS (SELECT * FROM write_data);
```

and

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_write_data;
```

instead of a variable. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I used:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_write_data AS (SELECT * FROM write_data);
```

and

```
 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_write_data;
```

instead of a variable. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into existing Object Relational Mapping tools if this is for a long term project.  If you just need a quick and dirty way to save the results of the query you can either write your own Data Value Object (i.e. an object that represents a single row of data) and create lists of these objects (i.e. the variable representing the data is a List of Row objects).  Or you could be even more streamlined about it and store the data returned by the query in a list of maps.  In Java this would be something like `List<Map<String,Object>>`.  In this case the Map represents a single row, the string represents the name of the column and the Object represents the value for that row.  The list represents the collection of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help, John. I would rather use a stored procedure for performance issues. I dont want to retrieve >10k datasets from the database and compare them to >1Mio datasets over about 10 columns. Is that an option?